# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Dim_Employee'

Tags: sql-server

Good day I have the following query.

It gives me the following error message

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint `'IX_Dim_Employee'`. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Dim_Employee'.
>
> The duplicate key value is (400613-CDMG0176, 5806195814589).

```
update b
set serviceno = a.serviceno,
idno = a.idno
from Fleet_StagingLive.dbo.stg_Employee a 
inner join Fleet_DataMartLive.dbo.Dim_Employee b 
on a.nodeid = b.nodeid
where b.nodeid <> -1 --fms
and b.nodeid <> -2  --ctrack
and a.IDNo = '5806195814589'
```

Comment: I am using sql server 2008

Comment: Well, the error message is very clear - your update statement have failed because of a unique constraint (or index) on the `Dim_Employee` table. Seems like the unique constraint contains two columns, one of them is the column you want to update.

Comment: I have an index but it's on the primary key, So is there no way to update service no?

Comment: You can update the service number, but not on that particular row to this particular value. Based on the error message, this is not a primary key violation, it's a unique index violation. If it was a primary key violation message would be different.

Comment: Is there any solution to this? I have roughly million records, would dropping the indexes on the table be a good idea?

Comment: "would dropping the indexes on the table be a good idea?" - since you clearly don't know *why the index was created*, nor, specifically, why it was created as unique, how could the next step in your thought process be "If strangers on the Internet tell me it's okay, I'll just drop it"? You might want to read about [Chesterton's Fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Chesterton%27s_fence)

Comment: dropping a unique index is probably a bad idea. This is the point where you should go consult with your team leader or DBA.